# Flexslider CSS/HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexslider

I have this issue with my flexslider in which no matter what I do, I just can't seem to place the slider at the very top left of the browser window. It seems as if there's a margin of 5 pixels on the top and the left.

If I were using simple CSS, this usually fixes it:
Top: 0
Left: 0

I've tried those elements on seemingly every single parameter within Flexslider's CSS and for the life of me I can't position it as such.

I'm using FlexSlider-2.6.3

Any suggestions?

Comment: does `body { margin: 0; }` fix it? if not post your code so we can see. we need a [mcve] to be able to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Also, check the containers for padding and margins.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips.

I found the answer. I've been staring at a computer screen for too long today.

Within .flexslider, I needed to apply {position: fixed} into the criteria.